# "The target "VerifyAlteredTargetsUsed" does not exist in the project" Error

Tags: visual-studio, build, compilation, msbuild, devenv

When I'm using msbuild tried to build a brand new repo (based on msbuild with .net 472)
I got this weird error:
[build error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ma3Al.png)

The interesting thing is that in each separate project I can build correctly. But when I use a dirs.proj and try to build both projects I got this issue. Here is the dirs.proj I'm using:
[dirs.proj file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLxU2.png)

Does any one know why this "VerifyAlteredTargetsUsed" does not exist issue happen and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReference  Include="######\######.csproj" />
        <ProjectReference  Include="######\####.sfproj" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.Common.targets" />
    <PropertyGroup>
        <BuildDependsOn>ResolveReferences</BuildDependsOn>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

It works in my test.